# Twilio Gather not pausing for input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, twilio

I'm having trouble getting Twilio to perform a Gather.  The call initializes just fine but instead of waiting for a user keypress, the Gather just falls through to the next statement and hangs up.

My environment is Visual Studio 2015.  .NET 4.6, MVC6, asp.net5.  I have the RC1 Update installed.  Nuget packages are Twilio version 4.4.1, Twilio.TwiML 3.3.6.

Here is a test WebAPI 2 controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OutboundCallController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        var twilioResponse = new TwilioResponse();
        twilioResponse.BeginGather(new { timeout = "60", numDigits = "1", action = "Foo", method = "POST" });
        twilioResponse.Say("Test Message Here");
        twilioResponse.EndGather();
        twilioResponse.Say("Fallthrough.  Goodbye.");
        return new ObjectResult(twilioResponse.ToString());
    }
}
```

When Twilio receives the below data it Says "Test Message Here Fallthrough.  Goodbye."  all at once, without pausing, then promptly hangs up.

Using ngrok I can see that the reponse to the Twilio POST to my controller  is:

```
<Response>
  <Gather timeout="60" numDigits="1" action="Foo" method="POST">
    <Say>Test Message Here</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Say>Fallthrough.  Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

Additionally, my Twilio log looks like (identical):

```
<Response>
  <Gather timeout="60" numDigits="1" action="Foo" method="POST">
    <Say>Test Message Here</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Say>Fallthrough.  Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

EDIT:

I've also tried changing the WebAPI to return a string instead of IActionResult.  Nothing changes, same result.

```
[HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {....}
```

ANSWER:

Turns out I wasn't returning the correct content type, I modified the return of the POST action, the full controller code is below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OutboundCallController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        var twilioResponse = new TwilioResponse();
        twilioResponse.BeginGather(new { timeout = "60", numDigits = "1", action = "Foo", method = "POST" });
        twilioResponse.Say("Test Message Here");
        twilioResponse.EndGather();
        twilioResponse.Say("Fallthrough.  Goodbye.");
        return Content(twilioResponse.ToString(), "application/xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674956/twilio-gather-issues-possibly-formatting-issue-either-no-gather-timeout-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just copied your generated [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to [twimlbin](http://twimlbin.com/) and was able to get it working with proper pause and without skipping.

Here's an exact copy of [your generated TwiML](http://twimlbin.com/external/6243e85791c791aa).

Obviously when you press a number, it fails because the action is only set to be `foo`. If you set that action to something else like the example below, you will see that upon pressing a number, you should also get a message that says "Hi there"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather timeout="60" numDigits="1" action="http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E" method="POST">
    <Say>Test Message Here</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Say>Fallthrough.  Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

Also, your C# code looks right but let me know you want to make your endpoint public so I can test it. It will be worth checking that what you're returning to Twilio is really XML (i.e. that it has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on top) and that its content type is really XML.

Happy to help with any other questions.

Comment: Thanks, you got me going in the right direction.  The content type was incorrect in the response.  I've edited my questions to show the change to my controller.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to have helped!