# Twilio "Gather" Issues (possibly formatting issue): Either no Gather() timeout wait time, or application error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twilio

I am running off the basic docs pages [[1]](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad/csharp), [[2]](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather). I note that page [1], under [in this block](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad/csharp?code-sample=code-add-another-route-to-handle-the-input-from-the-user&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x), uses the following example code:

```
public class VoiceController : TwilioController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public TwiMLResult Index()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Gather(numDigits: 1, action: new Uri("/voice/gather", UriKind.Relative))
            .Say("For sales, press 1. For support, press 2.");
        response.Redirect(new Uri("/voice", UriKind.Relative));
        return TwiML(response);
    }
}
```

When I use this code in my project, I get strange issues. The best I've figured out so far is that if I replace the `.Redirect(...)` with a `.Say(...)`, I note that there is **no pause for the `Gather`'s 5 seconds.** It just says the first message and then immediately says the second. I would make a guess that the `Redirect()` is also being called immediately, and leading to some kind of loop (although I only ever hear the `Say()` once during the buggy behaviour). Adding `timeout: 5` and `.Pause()` doesn't help, nor should it.*

On page [2], the code for the exact same thing [is written](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-complex-gather-with-actionmethod-and-nested-say&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x):

```
public class VoiceController : TwilioController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public TwiMLResult Index()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        var gather = new Gather(action: new Uri("/process_gather.php"),
            method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get);
        gather
            .Say("Please enter your account number,\nfollowed by the pound sign");
        response.Append(gather);
        response.Say("We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!");
        return TwiML(response);
    }
}
```

Well, almost exactly the same - it's not a controller method. Also, it's using a `Say()`. In this case, I am able to use the `Say()` to confirm it *does* wait the 5 seconds for the `Gather()`! However, the call always ends with a "We're sorry, an application error has occurred".

---

Question: I suspect this is just a syntax thing clashing with either out of date documentation, or my set up being subtly different. For example, I am `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` and `Twilio.AspNet.Core;`, which are not in the (first) example, and not using `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;` and `System.Web.Mvc;`, which are? **I can't find any specific documentation or other reason to think formatting on AspNetCore is different.**

Quite perplexing, I am wondering if someone could shed some light on this.

---

<sup>* Another bug that might be related: The DTMF input is very janky. I can't pin down exactly what it is, there is some reproduceable steps where I can demonstrate it only records the second of 2 digits pressed, but this rule doesn't explain some of the other jankiness in other functions. All functions are written with the same code, in the [1] style. **Either way, seems very likely related to `Gather()` not waiting 5 seconds.**</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had made a small oversight in my code causing the bug on method [2] from the OP. Therefore, I am writing this answer to be a good [denvercoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/) and let people having the issue above that the second way of writing the code worked for me, rather than [1]. Just had to get the param syntax and `HttpMethod.Get/Post` right, and got past the application error.

You can use response.ToString() to look at the xml being generated. The first method was creating the following **wrong** xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="/voice/gather/?id=" numDigits="1"></Gather>
  <Say>Please enter your 7 digit meter number.</Say>
  <Redirect>/voice</Redirect>
</Response>
```

The second creates the **correct** xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="/voice/gather/?id=" method="POST" numDigits="1">
    <Say>Please enter your 7 digit meter number.</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>/voice</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

The excellent practice, we are following to gather input from the user is:

First, initialize the voice response.
Then, use the Say method to tell the user what he/her needs to provide.
Then, use `Gather` and give a `timeout` (default is 5 seconds). **Note: Twilio adds a 5-second buffer by default to the timeout you provide.** Also, you can give a `numDigits` parameter to tell Gather how many digits you expect from the user before TwiML redirects to the action Uri.

Instead of the Redirect method, you can provide an action parameter inside gather as well.

You can set the request method of your webhook in your TwiML app configuration, see the screenshot below:

[image: TwiML WebHook Settings]

Here is an example, that worked very well for our project:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();

                response.Say("Please enter the briefing time in minutes.",
                    voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Woman, // voice of announcement
                    language: Say.LanguageEnum.EnGb); // language of announcement

                response.Append(
new Gather(input: new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf }.ToList(), // Dtmf is used to take input from the keypad.
                    timeout: 7, // 7 + 5 buffer by Twilio
                    numDigits: 2, // expecting a maximum of 2 digits from the user
                    actionOnEmptyResult: true,
                    action: Url.ActionUri("actionName", "controllerName")
                    ));
                return TwiML(response);
```

In your case, the code will look like that:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();

                response.Say("For sales, press 1");
                response.Say("For support, press 2");
                response.Append(new Gather(input: new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf }.ToList(),
                    numDigits: 1,
                    action: new Uri("/voice/gather")
                    ));
                return TwiML(response);
```

*You can redirect to /voice in your gather method if the user provides other inputs aside from 1 or 2 or if the user did not provide any input and your response is timed out.*